# GWT 2.8.2 : Native JS that seems not to be recognized

Tags: java, gwt

I have a problem with GWT execution. All compilation is fine, but at execution I have this error on console:

[image: error screenshot]

In String class it seems that the native JS is not recognized. I never had the problem before since I work with GWT, since 2 years. The problem is exactly the same with 2.7.0 GWT version. I use the super dev mode to recompile, but even with super dev mode on/off, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : the object was not a String, it was an int.

The server returned a Date and GWT was excepting a String. (So bad synchronisation with GWT front object and backoffice object). 
I think it transform the Date object to a timestamp and that was the int I saw in the front console. There was no method charCodeAt on a primitive type, so that explain the error.

Answer (score 0):

TypeError in JS usually means that an object was null, so a method couldn't be called on it (or a property couldn't be read).

Is there any chance the string is actually null there? This sometimes happens, where the Java methods get rebuilt in such a way that you don't detect a NPE as early as you would in Java.